# turning links swhite in a div using psudocode

Tags: css, hyperlink, pseudocode

Im trying to turn the color of links in a div to white but only in that div in css. Ive tryed pseudo code as below any help woul;d be appreciated.

.leftnav : a {color:white;}

Comment: Could you post your HTML & CSS (and whatever pseudo-code is)

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VE8Jf/1/)**

```
<div class="leftnav">
    <a>http:/google.com</a>
</div>

.leftnav a {color:black}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftnav a
{
color:white;
}
```

This is what you looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftnav a { color: white; }
```

You put a ":" in there that didn't belong there.